# error CS0201: Only assignment, call

Tags: c#

Hello Can Anybody hwlp me with this...

```
 if (distance < 0.50f) {
     theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth --;
     currentaDamage = damageToGive - (thePS.currentDefence);
     if (currentaDamage < 0) {
         currentaDamage = 0;
     }
 }
```

This works correctly, but it cause only -1 CurrentHealth. I want to - current damage,

If I'll do like this:

```
 if (distance < 0.50f) {
     theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth - currentaDamage;
     currentaDamage = damageToGive - (thePS.currentDefence);
     if (currentaDamage < 0) {
         currentaDamage = 0;
     }
 }
```

I've got an error CS0201: Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

Comment: But what is this - `theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth - currentaDamage;` supposed to do? You're just subtracting one value form another, you're **not storing this anywhere**, this is what the compiler is trying to tell you.

Comment: Did you mean to subtract the current damage **before** you calculate it?

Comment: Yes, I am not strong in c#.

Comment: Yes
    void Update () {

  currentaDamage = damageToGive - (thePS.currentDefence);
  if (currentaDamage < 0) {
   currentaDamage = 0;
  }

  if (attackTimer > 0)
   attackTimer -= Time.deltaTime;

  if(attackTimer <0)
   attackTimer = 0;

  if(attackTimer == 0){
   Attack ();
   attackTimer = coolDown;

  }
 }

Comment: Since `-=` wasn't what you needed then you need to explain what you *want*, not just "this code doesn't work".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the following line:

```
theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth - currentaDamage;
```

It should be rewritten as:

```
theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth = theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth - currentaDamage;
```

Why so? Because you want to decrement the `PlayerCurrentHealth` by `currentaDamage` and the `PlayerCurrentHealth` should have the vew value.

The following:

```
theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth--;
```

is equivalent to

```
theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth = theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth - 1;
```

Comment: Weird downvote. That's exactly the problem. An explanation should be required sometimes.

Comment: There is no error enymore, but is not get  -  currDmg from PlayerHP

Comment: I hope you didn't downvote just because a simple typo. A comment or an edit should be enough (in my opinion)

Comment: Well if I do like: 

    theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth = theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth - 1;  Then it works.

But :

    theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth = theHM.PlayerCurrentHealth - currentaDamage;    does not